# Why am I getting zero? Center of mass integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, centroid

Given a lamina $x^2 +y^2 = 1$ with density function $\sigma(x,y) = x+y$. Find the center of mass of the surface.

So first lets find the mass.

$$m= \int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}(x+y)\, dx\, dy$$

We can convert it into polar coordinates

$$m= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}(r \sin\theta +r\cos\theta)r \,dr \,d\theta$$

Solving it would result in $0$.

Why is that?

PS: I didn't write down the $M_x$ and $M_y$ here since with mass = $0$, I wouldn't be able to solve it anyway since I have to divide by $0$.

Comment: I'm confused. Circle or disk?

Comment: It should be circle

Comment: Sure it's not $\sigma=|x+y|$?

Comment: Speaking of finding the center of mass, I need to rephrase the question I was given. It says "..what can you say about its center of mass?"..I just assume it to be finding the COM. Maybe that's the point of the question..

Comment: But if it's a circle, why do you integrate over the disk? And your integral seems unrelated to center of mass ...

Comment: To get center of mass of a lamina, I would need Moment in the x direction and Moment in y direction. And then divide each of them with the mass to get center of mass (x,y). Right? The above integral is just to find the mass.

Answer (score 1):

The unit disk $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$ is symmetric under reflection through the origin.
That is, for every point $(x,y)$ on the unit disk,
the point $(-x,-y)$ also is on the unit disk.

Notice that according to your definitions, 
$$\sigma(-x,-y) = -x - y = -\sigma(x,y).$$
That is, for every point on the disk where the mass density is
$\sigma(x,y)$, there is a corresponding point where the
mass density is $-\sigma(x,y)$.
The masses in the neighborhoods of these two points exactly cancel.

Is is unusual to have negative mass density at a point.
I would check the setup of the problem to see if that is a mistake.

Comment: So does this mean the lamina is mass-less?

Comment: With that mass distribution, yes. Different parts of the lamina have mass, but the positive mass of one half of the lamina is canceled out exactly by the negative mass of the other half.

Comment: In that case, if an object is massless, where would its center of mass be? Anywhere or does not exist?

Comment: For example a point mass $m$ at $x$ and a corresponding negative point mass $-m$ at $-x$ result in a center of mass at $\frac{mx+(-m)(-x)}{m+(-m)}=\frac{2mx}0=???$. As you divide by the mass in the end, it does not make sense to speak o fcenter of mass for massless objects